# What is the difference between getRuntime().exec(php hello.php) and getRuntime().exec(array) in Java?

Tags: java, linux

In the following example, what is the difference between the two methods used to call "php hello.php" in Java? p1 vs p2?

```
String[] commands;
String command = "php hello.php";
commands[0] = "php";
commands[1] = "hello.php";

Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
Process p2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your particular scenario, none.

The multi-args version doesn't require the command line to be split up into arguments, and consequently it's provided for command-line arguments with spaces/tabs etc.

[From the Javadoc for the first (convenience) method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.io.File%29):

> More precisely, the command string is broken into tokens using a
>   StringTokenizer created by the call new StringTokenizer(command) with
>   no further modification of the character categories

(it's actually the version taking the environment too, but will get delegated to)

Comment: Hey Thanks for the help! As a follow up, do you know how to execute the functionality from Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cat someData.json) in linux, but under windows environment instead? I currently have Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C type printImagesJson-123.cache"); but the output value from readLine() is blank

Comment: cat simply writes the file to stdout, so I would rather read it in using java.io.FileReader. That would be platform independent, and you're not spawning off another process.